# React Native не работает Get запрос в локальной сети

Tags: reactjs, get, wifi, native

Есть устройство в локальной сети (умный дом), которое я могу включать и выключать из браузера без проблем с помощью get запроса (`http://192.168.0.100/Power?Power=1`).

Пишу приложение для android, на React Native, в эмуляторе все работает нормально, но после установки app на реальный телефон уже ничего не работает.

```
const test = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.0.100/Power?Power=1', true)
  };
return (
     <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => test()}>
     </TouchableOpacity>
       )
```

Comment: А ваш телефон находится в той же сети? Он видит ваш адрес 192.168...? Подозреваю, что вы к локальной сети хотите подключиться из вне.

Comment: Телефон подключен к тому же wifi, из браузера на телефоне все прекрасно работает, так же есть приложение MacroDroid на телефоне из него отправляю get и тоже все включает и выключает.
Из моего приложения проверял Post и Get запросы к внешним сайтам проходят отлично, а вот именно в локалку не хотят.